# C++ vector of class custom sort

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have C++ code. There is a vector of class. I need to sort this vector in a bit custom way.

Here is my class:

```
class Sales
{
   public:
      string customer_name;
      string category;
      string aircraft;
      string day;
      string time;
      int week;
      int ticket_price;
      string payment;

   public:
      Sales () { 
         customer_name = "";
         category = "";
         aircraft = "";
         day = "";
         time = "";
         week = 0;
         ticket_price = 0;
         payment = "";
      }

      Sales (string f_cat, string airc, string xday, string xtime, int xweek) {
         customer_name = "";
         category = f_cat;
         aircraft = airc;
         day = xday;
         time = xtime;
         week = xweek;
         ticket_price = 0;
         payment = "";
      }  
};
```

Lets say we have:

```
vector <Sales> list;
```

Imagine that list has got populated record And I want to get this sorted like below logic:

```
sort_string = day + time + week + category + aircraft;
```

Example records:

```
Sunday, 12:00, 1, Comm, b777
Monday, 10:00, 1, Comm, b777
Monday, 10:00, 1, Comm, a321
Monday, 12:00, 1, Comm, a321
Friday, 09:00, 1, Comm, a321
```

Expected Sort:

```
Monday, 10:00, 1, Comm, a321
Monday, 10:00, 1, Comm, b777
Monday, 12:00, 1, Comm, a321
Friday, 09:00, 1, Comm, a321
Sunday, 12:00, 1, Comm, b777
```

Is this possible? if Yes, then how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Define

```
bool Sales::operator<( const Sales& other ) // member
```

or

```
bool operator<( const Sales& lhs, const Sales& rhs) // global
```

and use `std::sort`.

---

Example with only two `int` variables, as they are the easiest ones:

```
bool operator<( const Sales& lhs, const Sales& rhs)
{
    if( lhs.week < rhs.week ) 
         return true;
    else if( lhs.week > rhs.week )  
         return false;

    if( lhs.price < rhs.price ) 
         return true;
    else if( lhs.price > rhs.price )  
         return false;

    // ...

    return false;
}
```

Of course, your definition will be more complicated, because the other fields are more complicated for comparing (the weekday for example), but I hope you get the point.

Then:

```
#include <algorithm>
// ...
std::sort( list.begin(), list.end() );
```

By the way, `list` is bad name for variable, as it may conflict with `std::list` in some cases.

Comment: how `str::sort` will know which variables to use in which order?

Comment: You define it in the body of the functions listed by Kiril above.

Comment: @ChrisL I am not familiar with this. Could you provide me an example?

Comment: This isn't exactly what you need but an example. If you wanted to sort by week, then you'd define `bool operator<( const Sales& lsh, const Sales& rhs) { return (lhs.week < rhs.week); }` //ie if the week is less on the left than the right return true else false. This logic is used by std::sort to order your container

Comment: @ChrisL if you can give me an example for 2 variables I think I can handle the rest

Comment: If I wanted to combine them to just one `if` I think I can do `if(( lhs.week < rhs.week) && (lhs.price < lhs.price)) return true;`

Comment: @Ozgur - depends on the logic. Written like this, you can have the following case: `lhs.week < rhs.week` **BUT** `lhs.price >= rhs.price` and this will `return false`, while I think it should return true. Am I wrong? It's really dependent on the logic you want for comparing.

Comment: Maybe you need `||` instead of `&&`? I don't know. The problem is, that you will not be able to compare `if( lhs.day < rhs.day )` because this will compare the strings lexically, not the way you want (meaning  `Friday` is less then `Monday`, for example). That's what I meant by "more complicated".

Comment: @kiril looks good to me - saves me writing it in a comment, i've upvoted your answer now.

Comment: @KirilKirov imagine all variables are `string` so actually what I will do  `xcomp = lhs.day + lhs.time + lhs.week + lhs.category + lhs.aircraft;`  and `ycomp = rhs.day + rhs.time + rhs.week + rhs.category + rhs.aircraft;`   `if(ycomp < xcomp) return true;`  <br /><br />do you this would work?

Comment: By the way, how can I do line break in comments? annoying

Comment: @Ozgur - `operator<` for `std::string` sorts the strings lexically, as I said above. I don't think that's what you need, I think you want semantic sort(watching each field), not lexical (combing everything into a string and then compare strings) (you cannot add new lines in comments :( )

Comment: @KirilKirov then how can I achieve multi variable comparison at one line? (as in above order exactly)?

Comment: Why you need it to be on the same line? You can write an ugly, extremely long condition with tens `||` and `&&` in it, but ... Trust me, you don't need it (it's ugly and very, _very_ error prone)

Comment: @KirilKirov If you see the `class` there are 8 variables in it. I want to sort the `vector` only based on 5 of them together and not individually as `if( lhs.week < rhs.week ) return true;` With this line any time `lhs.week < rhs.week` is it will return `true` where how about the day of the week and time of the day?. You see all connected.

Comment: @Ozgur - I don't get what's the problem. Anyway - it was an example how to do this. You should now implement your logic, which I obviously don't understand. But yes, it is possible and this is the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

if you will implement boolean function as member it must be const type

```
    bool operator<( const Sales& rhs) const{ 
        if (customer_name < rhs.customer_name ) return true; 
        if (category < rhs.category ) return true; 
        return false;
    }
```

See working [example](http://ideone.com/dUiBHj)

Comment: Why _"must"_ ? Maybe "should"?

Comment: It was not compiling for me until I put it.

Comment: @BorisIvanov this is what I get when I compile `test.cpp:73: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ':' token`  because of `for loops`

Comment: /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2269:19: error: passing ‘const Sales’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘bool Sales::operator<(const Sales&)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
    while (__pivot < *__last)